# last entry per group with additional conditions

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following code for MYSQL.

```
SELECT p1.* 
  FROM `tags` p1 
  LEFT 
  JOIN `tags` p2 
    ON (p1.cabinetid = p2.cabinetid AND p1.timestamp < p2.timestamp) 
 WHERE p2.timestamp IS NULL
```

I want to add the conditional "WHERE unitid = 5".  I'm having a brain fart moment and cannot figure out where to put that.

the source table looks like this:

```
Let me clarify what I want this to do.  I have one table.
```

The structure looks like this :

```
unitid - cabinetid - timestamp
5        -      6          - timestamp
5        -       7        - timestamp
6        -       6        -   timestamp
7       -        8        - timestamp
```

I want to get all entries for unitid 5, and get the latest entry for each cabinetid

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p1.*
  FROM tags p1 
  LEFT 
  JOIN tags p2 
   ON (p1.cabinetid = p2.cabinetid AND p1.timestamp < p2.timestamp) 
 WHERE p2.timestamp IS NULL 
   and unitid = 5
```

sorry if not right

Comment: he/she right add what table name so if p2 the p2.unitid=5

Comment: made changes to original question to better clarify.

Answer (score 0):

From which table unitid belongs then give table.unitid =5

Comment: Let me clarify some.
The table looks like this
id - cabinetid - unitid - timestamp

I want to get the latest entry for each cabinetid that has a unitid of 5.

putting it at the end as you did is not giving the desired results, that is limiting it to one entry for unit 5.

Comment: I fail to understand what you want to do

Comment: I added to my original question to make it easier to understand.   

I want to 1. only pull entries that match unitid = 5.    
2. acquire the latest entry for each cabinetid that meets the above criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  I just had to double nest the conditional.

```
SELECT o.* FROM( SELECT * FROM `tags` WHERE `unitid` = 6) o LEFT JOIN (

 SELECT * FROM `tags` WHERE `unitid` = 6) b 
ON o.cabinetid = b.cabinetid AND o.timestamp < b.timestamp 
WHERE b.timestamp is NULL
```

Comment: A UNION might be more usual here. Regardless, I suspect that there’s considerable scope GeForce improvement over this answer.

Comment: I'm sure you're right, I'd be very grateful to anyone who provided a better solution.

Comment: I’m sure I didn’t write GeForce. Pesky autocorrect :-(